# Search for WCF service in a LAN?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is there a way to search for the existence of a given WCF service in any of the computer of a local Network?

For example, I am looking for the Math/Add2Numbers service and I want to know which machines on the LAN provide it, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a super simple discovery example.  It does not use a config file, it is all c# code, but you can probably port the concepts to a config file.

share this interface between host and client program (copy to each program for now)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWcfPingTest
{
  [OperationContract]
  string Ping();
}
```

put this code in the host program

```
public class WcfPingTest : IWcfPingTest
{
  public const string magicString = "djeut73bch58sb4"; // this is random, just to see if you get the right result
  public string Ping() {return magicString;}
}
public void WcfTestHost_Open()
{
  string hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
  var baseAddress = new UriBuilder("http", hostname, 7400, "WcfPing");
  var h = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfPingTest), baseAddress.Uri);

  // enable processing of discovery messages.  use UdpDiscoveryEndpoint to enable listening. use EndpointDiscoveryBehavior for fine control.
  h.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
  h.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());

  // enable wsdl, so you can use the service from WcfStorm, or other tools.
  var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
  smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
  smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
  h.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

  // create endpoint
  var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
  h.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWcfPingTest) , binding,   "");
  h.Open();
  Console.WriteLine("host open");
}
```

put this code in the client program

```
private IWcfPingTest channel;
public Uri WcfTestClient_DiscoverChannel()
{
  var dc = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
  FindCriteria fc = new FindCriteria(typeof(IWcfPingTest));
  fc.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
  FindResponse fr = dc.Find(fc);
  foreach(EndpointDiscoveryMetadata edm in fr.Endpoints) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("uri found = " + edm.Address.Uri.ToString());
  }
  // here is the really nasty part
  // i am just returning the first channel, but it may not work.
  // you have to do some logic to decide which uri to use from the discovered uris
  // for example, you may discover "127.0.0.1", but that one is obviously useless.
  // also, catch exceptions when no endpoints are found and try again.
  return fr.Endpoints[0].Address.Uri;  
}
public void WcfTestClient_SetupChannel()
{
  var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
  var factory = new ChannelFactory<IWcfPingTest>(binding);
  var uri = WcfTestClient_DiscoverChannel();
  Console.WriteLine("creating channel to " + uri.ToString());
  EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(uri);
  channel = factory.CreateChannel(ea);
  Console.WriteLine("channel created");
  //Console.WriteLine("pinging host");
  //string result = channel.Ping();
  //Console.WriteLine("ping result = " + result);
}
public void WcfTestClient_Ping()
{
  Console.WriteLine("pinging host");
  string result = channel.Ping();
  Console.WriteLine("ping result = " + result);
}
```

on the host, simply call the WcfTestHost_Open() function, then sleep forever or something.

on the client, run these functions. It takes a little while for a host to open, so there are several delays here.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
this.server.WcfTestClient_SetupChannel();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
this.server.WcfTestClient_Ping();
```

host output should look like

```
host open
```

client output should look like

```
uri found = http://wilkesvmdev:7400/WcfPing
creating channel to http://wilkesvmdev:7400/WcfPing
channel created
pinging host
ping result = djeut73bch58sb4
```

this is seriously the minimum I could come up with for a discovery example.  This stuff gets pretty complex fast.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is WS-Discovery, but unfortunately, this is not included as part of the ws-* extensions in WCF.  There are some homegrown implementations of it.  Here's a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=P7g&q=wcf++ws-discovery&btnG=Search) for that.

Otherwise, you can implement an enterprise UDDI or registry solution by a third party vendor (like [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0609_mckee/0609_mckee.html) or [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/idm/uddi/default.mspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You could use UDDI to find it, but if there were multiple instances of the service, how would you decide which instance to use?